# What is the Boost equivalent of a HANDLE?

Tags: c++, boost

As the title states - what is the Boost equivalent to a Windows `HANDLE`?
I need to port some Windows specific code to Linux/OS-unspecific and it uses handles and their Functions (e.g. CloseHandle).

If the eqivalent is a `boost::mutex`, then why, and what is the difference between a Windows `HANDLE` and `CRITICALSECTION`?

I've loked for it in the boost documentation but I can't seem to find it.
Any help appreciated!

Comment: Are you expecting that Boost offers a magic library that offers instant porting from windows to linux?

Comment: I think you should tackle this from the other end: work out what the Linux equivalent APIs are and then use whatever types they do, rather than starting with trying to find an exact HANDLE equivalent. (FWIW HANDLE is just a void* IIRC, so you could at a pinch use that, assuming you Linux APIs use pointers to arbitrary structures too - but start with the Linux APIs and see what they use.)

Comment: No I don't but if it does, what would be the equivalent, and if it does not, how would i go about using Boost to achieve a similar thing?

Comment: "handle" is just a general term that means if you have eg a file handle `f` then `f` isnt the file, but it is just something that you can use instead of the file and whoever actually manages the file knows what real file belongs to what handle

Comment: Windows uses HANDLEs as an opaque, general object. You need to inspect the code and look at the code that creates and uses the HANDLEs to determine what kind they are, then map that to the corresponding generic type. You have already found a few HANDLEs that map to mutexes; I suggest you edit your question with concrete uses you did not find a map for.

Comment: Windows uses `HANDLE` to hide lots of different things, that don't have a single shared type on other operating systems. If you're only interested in a HANDLE representing a mutex then ask about that - there is no general answer to your current question (aka What Botje Said)

Answer (score 1):

There is no equivalent. `HANDLE` is a handle to a Windows kernel object.

That also makes it easy to explain the difference with a `CRITICAL_SECTION`. A Windows critical section is a non-kernel object; it only applies to your current process. That's similar to `std::mutex`. On Windows, `CreateMutex` creates a mutex object which is a kernel object that can be named, secured and shared between processes. That's why `CreateMutex` returns a `HANDLE`.

Note that `CreateFile` *also* returns a `HANDLE`. Just like mutexes, files can be named, secured, and shared between applications.

You will therefore need to find the true type of each `HANDLE` in your process, and replace it on a case-by-case basis.

BTW, we've got `std::mutex`, no need for `boost::mutex`. But `boost::interprocess::interprocess_mutex` *is* still relevant as it's the equivalent of a Windows kernel mutex.